# Usage of select_tag in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
  <%= form_tag(:controller => "home", :action => "create", :method => 
  "post") do %>
    <br><br>


    <%= label_tag("City") %>
    <%= select_tag( "<option value=1>c1</option>
      <option value=2>ctnry</option>
      <option value=3>cntry</option>
      <option value=4>cntry</option>" , :class => "span2" ) 
    %>
  <% end %>
```

What is the problem related with this? have any issues with form_tag

Comment: 7.7 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "name" attribute is missing in your select. Look at these links for help on the generation of `<select>` via Rails:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html